# How to store data into specific directories after reading it from kafka consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka topic from which I need to read JSON data using consumer, but based on specific tags in the data I need to store it in different directories in the drive.

How do I achieve this? Can the data be directly parsed before storing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear *where* those directories will exist, but you can try using the [HDFS Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/configuration_options.html#hdfs-config-options) (which will work with an HDFS-Compatible filesystem, including local disk) with the `FieldPartitioner` to designate which fields within the Kafka records are to be made as directories in the format of `/topic-dir/topic-name/field1=value/field2=value`

To write to local disk, set `store.url=file:///some/path`

Otherwise, Spark, Flink, regular Kafka consumer etc, you can consume that data and construct directories on your own.

> Can the data be directly parsed before storing it?

Depends on how you consume the data...